# Find a unique integer $g$ such that $g^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a unique integer $g$ such that $g^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$ where $p > 3$

Originally, I thought that it was equal to $1$ since $1^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$.

$g$ has to belong in the reduced residue system of $p$.

Comment: As pointed out in Spooky's answer, it makes no sense to ask for a unique integer here.  There are many integers $g$ such that $g^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  Please fix your question.

Comment: @ErickWong fixed

Comment: It still says "unique" which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

$g^2 \equiv 1 \bmod{p} \iff (g+1)(g-1) \equiv 0 \bmod{p} \iff g \equiv \pm 1 \bmod{p}$. Since $p$ is prime. These are distinct since $p \neq 2$.

So there are no unique integers that satisfy this, in fact there are two residues classes mod $p$ where every integer in that residue class satisfies that congruence.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the unique integer we have to find is in the reduced residue system of p. So if you remove -1, your answer is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @DonLarynx No, in the reduced residue system you still have $p-1$.  That is the point of a residue system, that it captures equivalences of integers that lie outside it (in the "reduced" case, as long as it's relatively prime to the modulus).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $p$ is a prime. If so, we need
$$p \mid (g^2-1) \implies p \mid (g+1)(g-1)$$
Since $p$  is a prime, either $p \mid (g+1)$ or $p \mid (g-1)$. Further, since $p$ is greater than $3$, it cannot divide both simultaneously. Hence, this forces $g \equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

Either $g=1$ or $g=-1$. So either $g=1$ or $g=p-1$.